# New Features on Stack Overflow Jobs: Company Updates, Follow, and Ads

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, announcement

Today, August 31, we released three new features on Stack Overflow Jobs that make it easier to connect with your favorite companies.

---

#### Company Updates & Follow

We updated Company Pages by introducing two new features: Company Updates and Company Follow.

[image: company updates & follow features]

The Company Updates feature allows companies to regularly post content to their company page, giving users a better understanding of a company’s mission, tech stack, projects, and employee initiatives.

The Company Follow feature ensures that this content is shown to interested users. By following a company, users opt into a weekly digest email with new content and relevant jobs from all the companies they follow.

---

#### Company Ads

Similar to job ads and company page ads, we will occasionally show a new ad type in the sidebar to help users discover interesting companies to follow:

[image: example of company ads]

This ad shows users a few companies in their area along with their tech stack, followers, job openings, and whether they have recently posted new content. As always, if a user dismisses a company, they will not see them in company ads or search.

We’re excited to bring you these changes. A big shoutout to [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6347688/ian?tab=profile), [John](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/682840/john-m-wright?tab=profile), [Juan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472675/juan?tab=profile), [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523776/benjamin-hodgson?tab=profile), [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189572/max?tab=profile), [Piper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7851896/piper-lawson?tab=profile), and Sarah for all their hard work!

We hope that these new features, along with our robust [Company Search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies), will better connect our users to interesting, technologist-first companies and opportunities.

Comment: I see no comments and 10 downvotes. Why downvoting the announcement and providing no feedback? Are the changes affecting negatively someone's user experience? Or is it about that devs are wasting time for something not useful? I didn't vote myself, because I am neutral.

Comment: @Sinatr, I imagine people downvoting because they like to see dev time spent elsewhere. Personally I'm quite neutral in this matter, as I am not interested in seeking a job. Also I fully understand that SO.inc needs this revenue stream to keep the rest of the network running. In order for them to make this money they need relevant jobs to offer to users. To have those relevant jobs they need companies willing to advertise their positions, which requires dev time to meet wishes/demands of these companies.

Comment: Why does this have one close vote as “needs more focus”?

Comment: @user4642212 AFAICT, many discussion questions of this type get closed, reopened, closed, reopened several times. I think of it as a troll.

Comment: @user4642212 The easiest solution would be if posts by diamonds would just not be closeable. Regarding the downvotes one should keep in mind that voting on meta is different. People downvote clear content because they disagree with it. So maybe it's just a sign of general disagreement.

Comment: Using one's close vote on an announcement from staff is just really **counter productive**. Even if one doesn't agree with a feature or an announcement, being informed about it is quite important, in my opinion. I'm not sure what's going on with those close votes, but I'd speculate they're used as a super-downvote, which is inappropriate.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I'm a bit skeptical about how useful this would be. "Company’s mission" -- depends on whether it's something specific or the usual "empowering [our investors' theoretical ROI via buzzwords]" jargon, "tech stack" -- useful in that I can skip over the company if I don't have that experience unless they specifically say they are flexible in their requirements, "projects" -- probably similar use to "the stack", "employee initiatives" -- this is a bit unclear to me, what is this referring to?

Comment: @jrh An employee initiative can mean any project or program initiated and/or run by employees that wasn't mandated by the company. Charity projects, employee resource groups, etc. Someone arranging a totally voluntary Lunch and Learn series for their office would be an example.

Comment: I'd say that if you're really interested in a company, getting an email when they have relevant positions open is a good idea. Being aware of what projects and initiatives are currently happening in that company can be helpful in interviews. Also, this is all opt-in so it's not like we're about to be flooded with unwanted emails.

Comment: If we search by a tech stack tag can we please only have results with that tag included? If no results then no results.

Comment: @puneet-mulchandani, thank you for sharing that with us. I go to the ads from time to time and it is interesting to know better the companies.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Close votes are different. Once a post gets closed, no one can Answer it ..and deleted votes start appearing.

Comment: +1'ing what @BSMP said above. The company updates feature intentionally gives companies more flexibility in sharing the information they want to with potential candidates. As a candidate, looking at the kinds of content and stories that companies choose to share is another good signal to help evaluate whether that company is a good fit. And yes, this whole experience is opt-in for users. We always want to make sure to provide candidates with content that's relevant to their interests!

Answer (score 18):

Small suggestion: the "tech stack" feature could be confusing to job seekers because the "tech stack" tags don't require the existence of jobs with that tag.

For example, [this company](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/british-columbia-investment-management-corporation-bci) has `xsd` and `integration` in their tech stack.  However, clicking on either of these tags leads you to an [empty search result](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-integration) -- not only does this company not have a job with the tag, but neither does any other company.

Perhaps clicking on a tag in the "tech stack" should lead to a [company search of that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?q=xsd), rather than jobs.

Comment: this is a really good suggestion, thanks for the feedback! We're already in talks about some major updates to the Company Search experience, will make sure to include this as part of that discussion.

Answer (score 3):

I wound up on this page because I clicked "Follow" on a company, then I wondered what that was supposed to mean and supposed to cause to happen next.

I could not determine from the StackOverflow Jobs web UI what the "Follow" actual does. Nor can I find a list of companies that I have explicitly "Followed".

Please add a place where I can see what I have followed in the past (similar to how I can see every StackOverflow question that I have ever upvoted).

Also, I'm still not entirely sure I understand what the intended outcome of clicking "Follow" is.

Does a company see how many followers they have? (If so, this could give a company some indication that perhaps even if their current job opening didn't garner many applications, there is still something about their company that people found appealing.)